# What is peer IP address in OpenVPN?

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

As a result of `ip addr` command on my Linux box, I can see that the `tun` interface of `OpenVPN` has a **peer IP address**. What does it exactly do?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198501/purpose-of-ip-addresses-on-tun-interface read over some comments too

Comment: @ITSnugglesm, actually I could not understand the question exactly, maybe I am missing something in how does tun work (I know it is layer 3, and I know that it carried IP packets from the client to the server, then the server plays the role of router and is responsible somehow to redirect these packets to other clients).

Comment: Second part: I cannot get what the the question is trying to ask. Specifically when he said *ip route add 10.10.3.0/24 via 192.168.1.2 dev tun0 where 192.168.1.2 is the peer IP address. However, for point-to-point links, one should be able to route traffic directly onto interface, e.g. ip route add 10.10.3.0/24 dev tun0*. Could explain about that a bit please?

Comment: @ITSnuggles, so I tried again and again to understand it, what I get is simply that this peer IP is completely arbitrary and useless? Just to be sure,  is the peer (or remote) address in Windows and Linux, that IP that appears under gateway section?

Comment: I'm not personally an expert on the topic of OpenVPN and use a different VPN solution but based on some brief reading on OpenVPN and the peer IP address, I wanted to share that post with you as FYI but I cannot speak to anything in particular with it at the moment since I'm not 100% certain myself; just that the post might be helpful potentially only.